# Clash between plots and printed text in Julia notebook

Tags: plot, jupyter-notebook, julia

I have a Julia Jupyter notebook in which I generate plots with Plots, e.g., something like

```
thxpplot=plot(title=title,xlabel="T (K)",ylabel="V/V0")
thxpplot=plot!(Tplt,Vplt/V0,label=mat,color="red")
display((thxpplot))
```

and also text output, e.g.,

```
@printf("%s: %s (%d atoms)\n","Material",mat,N)
```

Annoyingly, both output streams don't seem to be synchronized. It frequently happens, especially in larger examples than this, that a part of the printed text appears before the plot and the rest after it, even though the succession of instructions as given by the code clearly separates both. How can I ensure proper synchronization between these output streams, or in other words, how can I flush the output buffers immediately? I don't have the impression that this is an issue in Python notebooks.

Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can flush the standard output with

```
flush(stdout)
```

However, if you mix plots with text be aware that plots use the `display` command rather than `println` and sometimes you might still run into synchronization issues because those streams are handled separately by Jupyter.

The solution in that case is to use:

```
display("some text you want to display")
```

In this way you will be able to control the order of output.

In your case instead of `@printf` you might want to use:

```
display(@sprintf("whatever you want to print"))
```

This however uses a default `text/plain` MIME type (and adds quotes etc).

Your results could be nicer via different MIME type:

```
display("text/json", @sprintf("%s: %s (%d atoms)\n","Material",4,5))
```

Or you can even use HTML

```
display("text/html", @sprintf("%s: <b>%s</b> (<b>%d</b> atoms)\n","Material",4,5))
```

Comment: While that seems to fix the issue with the order, I found at least two disadvantages: 1. The argument of @sprintf is displayed in quotes, contrary to my original intention; 2. Not all of the formatting instructions are translated, specifically `\t` and `\n` are reproduced verbatim.